# Qmake, setting up environment

Tags: c++, qt

I am following this [qt tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/qt).

```
helloworld.pro

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = helloworld
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPushButton button ("Hello world!");
    button.show();

    return a.exec(); // .exec starts QApplication and related GUI, this line starts 'event loop'    
}
```

Type the following shell commands to build the program.

```
qmake -project
```

Error:

```
PS E:\QT_tut\Tut_cmake_1\nSR> qmake -project
Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Output:
===================
===================
Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?
PS E:\QT_tut\Tut_cmake_1\nSR>
```

QT: 5.12.12
VS: 2019

But,  I can run this program  using QT GUI.

Comment: When you build from the Qt Creator (I assume), can you get a list of the full and complete build output? What compiler is it using? Is it also using the MSVC C++ compiler `cl`? Or is it using e.g. MinGW and the `g++` compiler?

Comment: MSVC2017_64bit-Debug

Comment: Then did you run the Visual Studio prepared Power Shell? Or run the scripts to set up the Visual Studio command-line environment (which does things like adding the `PATH` so the compiler could be found)? In the Windows start menu folder for Visual Studio, there should be a menu-item for running a command-line shell with the proper environment.

Comment: It works with Visual studio command line, but using  "make" getting error. No exe. made. Error: make command is not found.

Comment: `make` or `qmake`? Two different programs. And `qmake` is probably not in the default `PATH`, you need to either add it, or specify the full path for the `qmake.exe` program.

Comment: make. In tutorial   i need to type qmake -project   qmake    make. I think make command is to make exe files. Should I download it. link ? I tried make-3.81-bin\bin\make.exe, but i does nothing

Comment: We seem to be veering into a different problem from the one asked about in the original post. If you have two different problems please post two different questions.

Comment: What is the output when you type `cl`? It should be something like

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++-Optimierungscompiler Version 19.28.29913 für x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Syntax: cl [ Option... ] Dateiname... [ /link Linkeroption... ]
```

(most likely not in German though)

Comment: E:\QT_tut\Tut_cmake_1\src>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++-Optimierungscompiler Version 19.29.30038.1 für x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Syntax: cl [ Option... ] Dateiname... [ /link Linkeroption... ]   My problem is how to make exe. i tried nmake but getting error fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "qapplication": No such file or directory

Comment: For MSVC it's 'nmake' not 'make'